# File Chooser with cloud support for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios

Is there any file chooser library for Android and iOS that I can integrate into my application, with support for:

- Files from the SD Card
- Dropbox
- Google Drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found one - [Filepicker.io](https://www.filepicker.io/).

Looks fantastic so far.